Sitecore DR Database Question
Setup:
Hello I have a DB question regarding setting up Sitecore 10.3 in Azure app service in an active/active configuration for DR. The idea is for CD instances in site A and site B (different zones) to share traffic, then if something happens in site A we can fail over to B. We will only have one CM active at a time (site A unless we failover, in which case we would be using site B CM)
Our DB is Azure SQL configured in a failover group. We have an instance in site A that replicates to site B. So any content changes from A will be replicated to B automatically.
We're using Sitecore in CMS only mode - no xDB or marketing (Core, Master, Web, ExpForms DBs only)
Problem trying to solve:
The CD instances in site B are currently configured to point to DB instance in site A and the latency is high.
Question is can we make our CDs in site B connect readonly to the Core, Web and ExpForms DBs in site B where the latency is much lower?

Create read replicas of your Core, Web, and ExpForms databases in Azure SQL Database. These replicas will be geographically closer to your CD instances in both sites (A and B) for improved read performance. I have not used it but I think this would satisfy your requirement.

You should be fine to point your CDs in Site B to the replica WEB database in Site B, given there is no need to be writing data back to the database.
The CD role no longer requires access to the CORE database (from SC9.1 I believe), so this shouldnt be an issue.
The issue you may find though is with both the MESSAGING and EXPERIENCEFORMS databases, as these are shared between CM and CD environments.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/content-delivery--cd-.html
